# Azure Data Factory: Extract filenames from json, append extension and copy it to target

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

How do I copy files using Azure Data Factory by reading file names from a json where the keys to each elements are filenames (each filename is a sequence of digits) but the source directory has filenames with an extension
i.e: key 1 in json = filename_1
file in source = filename_1.tgz

```
{
    "filename_1": {
        "task_info": string,
        "text_id": int,
        "text": string,
        "worker_id": int,
        "gender": string,
        "age": string,
        "pincode": int
    },
    "filename_2": {
        "task_info": string,
        "text_id": int,
        "text": string,
        "worker_id": int,
        "gender": string,
        "age": string,
        "pincode": int
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to extract filenames, please share the error with me if you tried

Comment: I've been struggling with it for the past 48 hours with no avail. The thing is, there is no documentation on such a thing so its making it really hard to even know what I'm doing is even right. I've tried to reading the json using foreach activity but i have no idea where to go from there

Comment: Are there any other files that have the same name i.e., starting with `filename_1` for example or only one file `filename_1.tgz` exists?